# List comprehension with double loop

Tags: python, list

How I can write these loops using a list comprehension in python?

```
X = [i for i in range(3)]
Y = [i for i in range(2)]
my_list = []
for x in X:
    ccnt= 0 
    for y in Y:
        ccnt = ccnt +1 
        my_list.append([x * y,ccnt])
 
print(my_list);

mysuper_list =  [[[x*y , ccnt] for x in X] ccnt= 0 for y in Y  ccnt= ccnt + 1]
```

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.  You've dropped code on us without showing what's wrong with it.

Comment: Generally you can't accumulate in a list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

Might not be the most efficient, but gets the job done:

```py
mysuper_list = [[x*y, i+1] for x in X for i, y in enumerate(Y)]
```